# "have too acidic of something" or "have something that is acidic"?

Tags: grammar

Tell me please if there is any difference between the two construction. Here is the context:

> It’s important to note that while **having too acidic of an environment** in your body can have negative health consequences...
>
> It’s important to note that while **having an** **environment that is too acidic** in your body can have negative health consequences...

If these sentences are identical in their meaning, then which construction is more formal and which is more natural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is non-standard, mainly American, conversational, casual. The second is normal standard English.

"Of insertion" - that is, using 'of' in this way, e.g. too big of a problem, how hard of a job will it be? is mostly confined to American casual speech, and is hardly ever encountered in written English except in reported speech.

> ...dialectal “of a” usages are
>   becoming acceptable idioms in casual speech and informal writing.
>   However, we still wouldn’t recommend them in formal English, written
>   or spoken.
>
> In fact, this dialectal construction—like “how long of a drive”—isn’t
>   found much in print anyway, except in the most casual writing.
>
> Fowler’s Modern English Usage (rev. 3rd ed.) calls it an informal oral
>   usage that’s confined, so far, to American English.
>
> Merriam-Webster’s says the same: “Our evidence shows the idiom to be
>   almost entirely oral; it is rare in print except in reported speech.”
>
> As M-W concludes: “The only stricture on it suggested by our evidence
>   is that it is a spoken idiom: you will not want to use it much in
>   writing except of the personal kind.”

[Not that big of a deal?](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2014/01/not-that-big-of-a-deal.html)

Answer (score 3):

SUPPLEMENTAL to Michael Harvey's answer:

*Too ADJ of a* is, as Michael Harvey says, a colloquial use which is deprecated in formal contexts.

Note, however, that you have alternatives:

> . . . having a too acidic environment . . . *without the* of *is formally proper, as is*
>   . . . having too acidic an environment . . .

And if the superlative has a following complement the complement must follow the modified noun, and the entire construction may follow it:

> . . . having an environment too acidic to maintain mineral reserves . . .
>   . . . having too acidic an environment to maintain mineral reserves . . .